# Need Diagram Control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

We are looking for a Diagram Control/Component in Silverlight which enables us to create and deploy Network Diagrams. Also with which we should be able to traverse the diagram created, save it as a file (e.g. XML), load it, create custom nodes/controls with simple animation controls etc.

Can anyone let me know of any such component/tools in Silverlight that cater to our specified requirements?

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774112/do-silverlight-apis-exist-for-diagramming

Answer (score 1):

Try [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/silverlight/Diagram) Diagram for Silverlight. Check out their demos [here](http://samples.syncfusion.com/silverlight/8.2.0.18/default.aspx?product=diagram)

Comment: Save and load support is planned in their upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion have Diagram Component for Silverlight platform. This control is a common control for Drawing and Creating Diagram with lot of features and it will support Save and Load in many types.

1. Saving and loading as Xaml file.
2. Printing also possible.

Please visit the following link for more information.

Link: http://silverlight.syncfusion.com/samples/Silverlight/#/User%20Interface%20Edition/Diagram

Please let me know if you have any further clarifications.
Regards,
Sundar M

Answer (score 1):

If the question is still actual you can try [SharpShooter Diagrams](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Diagrams.aspx?lang=en) of PerpetuumSoft. It supports all the features you've mentioned and more.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [NOV Diagram](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-diagram-control-overview.aspx). Check the Silverlight demo [here](http://examplesnovsilverlight.nevron.com/)

Full disclosure: I work at Nevron

Comment: avoid link only answers -- at least summarize the linked content, then include for reference